# Replace Java applet loader image

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I have a JSP page like this.

```
<jsp:plugin type="applet" codebase="." code="ViewerApplet.class" align="center" width="100%" height="600" jreversion="1.6" archive="icepdf-core.jar, icepdf-viewer.jar, icepdf-applet.jar">
    <jsp:params><br>
        <jsp:param  name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx128m" /><br/>
        <jsp:param name="classloader_cache" value="true" /><br/>
        <jsp:param name="url" value="<%=test%>" />
    </jsp:params>
    <jsp:fallback>
        <p>Unable to load applet</p>
    </jsp:fallback>
</jsp:plugin>
```

Before the applet get executed, I get a [Java loader gif image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhYRR.jpg). I want
to replace that image with my own image. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Special Attributes of Applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html#specialattributes) & the (poorly named) `image` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good at applets but a quick research shows that you need to put the code in the `init()` method of your `ViewerApplet` class.

Comment: I think that your Ctrl+V was broken and that you didn't pay close attention to the preview/result while posting the answer.

Comment: @BalusC - Sorry, didn't get you.

Comment: You said "this code", but I don't see any line. Right now after the fix to "the code" it's even more vague. What code are you talking about?

Comment: Oh you're right. I was referring to the code that has to go in the Applet. I didn't write one because I'm not good at Applets. Care to help the OP?